# How do call the input value on reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, fetch-api

Here is my form on react... I need to get the value of the input but whenever I check the network the following is undefined. Please help me; it adds data but null.

```
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text"
            
            value={this.props.Employee_Name} 
             onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
            /> 
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td>
       <input type="text"
          
             name="Address"
             value={this.props.Address}/>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Department</td>
      <td>
       <input type="text"
               value={this.props.Department}
      /> 
      </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>

  </div>
  </div>
  <div className="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info"  onClick = { this.handleSubmit.bind(this, this.Employee_Name ,this.Address ,this.Department)}  value =" Add Employee"/>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

and this part is my code for fetching the API for post method so it will send the data on the API.

```
handleSubmit( name, address,department){
  debugger
 const data = {
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail?', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
  .then(function(response) {
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // Error :(
  });
}
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleSubmit` function you are passing the value as

```
onClick = { this.handleSubmit.bind(this, this.Employee_Name ,this.Address ,this.Department)}
```

But I don't see `this.Employee_Name ,this.Address ,this.Department` defined and containing the value for respecctive inputs. I think you should be passing the props and have a `onChange` on `Address` and `Department` too.

Try

```
onClick = { this.handleSubmit.bind(this, this.props.Employee_Name ,this.props.Address ,this.props.Department)}
```

Comment: If your props are being changed properyl, you should see the values in the handleSubmit function, See what you are getting there

Comment: being changed properly? what do you mean?

Comment: You have an onChange function on name for instance, `value={this.props.Employee_Name} 
                 onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}`, if you write the handleChange function properly to update the value in the parent which is then being passed to the current component as Employee_Name props

Comment: ive tried that too but the input are still undefined

Comment: Try `handleSubmit = ( name, address,department) => { console.log(this.props.Employee_Name)`

Answer (score 0):

For doing it the react way,

You'll need to set the props into state and render the component form like this :

```
<input type="text"
                   value={this.state.form.department}
         onChange={(e)=>this.changed(e,'department')} 
/>
```

Similar way, you can change other input fields.

**And define the changed function to be like this:**

```
changed(e,key){
  var state=Object.assign({},this.state);
  state.form[department]=e.target.value;
  this.setState({state})
}
```

**This sets the input values of form by user in the state of component.**

**Now, For the post request data:**

```
const data = {
      'Employee_Name': this.state.form.name,
      'Address':this.state.form.address,
      'Department': this.state.department
    }
```

or as you're doing:

```
    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info"  
onClick = { this.handleSubmit.bind(this, this.state.form.employee_Name ,this.state.form.address ,this.state.form.department)}  
value =" Add Employee"/>
```

Comment: i think that will work for the update part,... im working on the adding an employee.. ive tried that on the put method and its working..

Comment: Can you please specify then what issue you're facing ?

Comment: im adding another employee but when im adding it adds empty values

Comment: Yeah because you're trying top pickup form values in a wrong way.

Comment: Are you still trying to update the props,not the state ? because I must say that props are supposed to be read-only!

Comment: im telling you im not updating... im adding an employee.. ive already used the state part on the update part!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Example 1

This example stores the input values into props **as the user types**.
The className will be used to map to the state values.

Inside render method:

```
<input
    type="text"
    className="Employee_Name"
    onChange={this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)}
/>

<input
    type="text"
    className="Address"
    onChange={this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)}
/>

<input
    type="text"
    className="Department"
    onChange={this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)}
/>
<button
    type="submit"
    onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
    >
    SUMBUT
</button>
```

The `handleKeyUp` function sets the state

```
handleKeyUp(e) {
   let inputType = e.target.className
   let value = e.target.value
   let obj = {}
   obj[inputType] = value

   this.setState(obj)

    return
}


handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const { name, address, department} = this.state
    // do your fetch here

}
```